# Google+ OAuth How to store data retrieved and use it for Authentication

Tags: c#, android, oauth, google-api, google-plus

I am building an app using Xamarin in C#. My app can do the following:

1.) Display Google+ Login UI.

2.) Authenticate User and retrieve the access token.

3.) Use the access token to retrieve the User's sensitive information from Google.

4.) Takes this information (email,picture,name etc) and stores it in my database on a server using JSON and https.

5.) Returns that storing it was a success and application can continue.

What I am missing is when a user opens the app again, how can I authenticate them without them having to open up the login page again? I'm a bit confused as they are authenticated via Google+ API they have no password. I was thinking of doing the following:

1) Storing the token in the database as the password (hashed and salted obvs!)

2) Storing the token + email on the phone.

3) On logging into the app it asks the server if the token and email match if so information is then passed from server to app and the app continues.

Just a bit confused and I would like to do this properly without cutting corners!
[image]
J

Comment: Are you using Firebase by any chance?

Comment: No I'm not, I'm using MySQL

Comment: Hi James. I am writing an Android App. I am using Firebase for Authentication and storage. After a user logs in with their Google credentials and then close the app, next time they open the app, the app checks to see if the user is logged in. In most cases they are already logged in. If they are not,  they are prompted to reenter their credentials.